# Impedir download TWebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi

Possuo 1 WebBrowser que quando carregado uma URL ele deve carregar uma imagem de acordo com uma consulta no BD. Ocorre que a primeira vez que é feita a solicitação ele abre a tela para salvar essa imagem, se fechar essa janela ele prossegue normalmente. Alguma forma de cancelar o donwload?

Answer (score 1):

No evento `OnDownloadBegin` você pode programar um `Abort`.
Dessa forma ele irá interromper o download, porém, deve-se ter cuidado com esse procedimento, em alguns casos ele poderá interromper o carregamento da página.

```
procedure TForm5.WebBrowser1DownloadBegin(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Abort;
end;
```

Eu particularmente não uso o `TWebBrowser` (que é um instância do Internet Explorer (6x se não engano)) que não suporta HTML5 e péssimo no processamtno do `js`.

Hoje estou usando o Chromium, recomendo dar uma pesquisada sobre o assunto!

Comment: Já me falaram desse Chromium. Não sei se é nativo do delphi nas últimas versões mas uso o Delphi 10 Seattle e tem esse componente.

Comment: É um Open Source. não é nativo!